# How to customize WooCommerce CSS

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to customize the default CSS for WooCommerce. I have followed tutorials online however I have found that when I try to override the WooCommerce css in my main themes stylesheet it will only work if I include !important. Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks

My understanding is that I want to reenqueue the woocommerce stylesheets so that they are imported after my theme stylesheet is.

```
function carolynjudge_resources() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'carolynjudge_resources');
```

Comment: This is a theming issue and so is related to your theme *(+child theme)*… It depends on how the CSS of the theme are registered/enqueued in wordpress… You can manage to include your theme CSS with `wp_enqueue_style()` function after all CSS files (at last), and this way you will not need `! important` …

Comment: I have added my enqueue code, how would I need to modify this?

Comment: something like: `wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('woocommerce-layout-css', 'woocommerce-general-css', 'woocommerce-smallscreen-css'));` … you have to put as thirds argument an array of the CSS ids that are loaded in wordpress … see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/ …
 Theming is not my speciality, and this is classic to wordpress theming